# Back-propagation for training neural networks

Tags: algorithm, neural-network

I want to use [this article](http://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CE4QFjAA&url=http://www.zju.edu.cn/jzus/downloadpdf.php?doi=10.1631/jzus.A0820154&ei=XBDwT4XQB82UsgampMiMDw&usg=AFQjCNHg4RBVqTv_TeDg6ahkvZDYfUs4Gw&sig2=X2Y15mNx7ZWV1qRblXXzoQ) for neural network construction, but I meet some problems with the update algorithm of the weight vectors. Specifically, with formulas [marked red](http://saveimg.ru/show-image.php?id=19b9f3007a8e61f903b6a595917474fe).
Can anybody help me to understand, what is the hm(i) and the symbol "|" means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like the [back-propagation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back-propagation) computation for the gradient of the training error of a neural network.  [Bishop](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/cmbishop/prml/) (on page 244) lists a key formula as:

```
δj = h'(aj) SUM(k, wkj δk)
```

The `δ` are the errors between the predicted and labeled values of the hidden or output nodes.  The `δ` terms on the right side have been already calculated, and correspond to the next layer output-ward from the one being considered.

The `h'` term is the derivative of the non-linear [activation function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activation_function), which is typically  the [sigmoid function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function) or `tanh`.  The listed `hm` in your image looks like the derivative of `tanh` with a change of variables.

The vertical bar is a syntax for evaluation: `f(t) = f(x) | t`.  I can't quite tell what the expression in your image is; I could be wrong.